# Maven Build : 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

when I try to build a spring-boot project I am getting 403 Forbidden errors for a particular repository. This causes the build to fail.

Dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Error:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml from/to 
SpringFramework (https://maven.springframework.org/milestone/): Authorization failed for 
https://maven.springframework.org/milestone/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml 403 
Forbidden
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.5.0-M1 is 
missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.5.0-M1 is 
missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.5.0-M1 is 
missing, no dependency information available

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gtt-v2-sample-track-salesorders-service: Could not 
resolve dependencies for project com.sap.gtt.v2:gtt-v2-sample-track-salesorders- 
service:jar:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.5.0-M1, 
org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.5.0-M1, 
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.5.0-M1: Failure to find 
org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.5.0-M1 in 
https://maven.springframework.org/milestone/ was cached in the local repository, resolution 
will not be reattempted until the update interval of SpringFramework has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I checked in the Maven Repository it is mentioned like milestone repository. Not sure what do, please help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you try with the url `https://repo.spring.io/milestone` for the repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Spring Milestones or Release Candidates you need to add the following repository to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository> 
        <id>repository.spring.milestone</id> 
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name> 
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url> 
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

If you just want to use released Spring versions there is no need to add any new repository into the `pom.xml` because all release artifacts are published to Maven Central, but in this case you might want to change the dependency to:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The repository scheme **must** be `https:`. `http:` is returning 403. It was redirecting via 302 as late as 10/27/2021. However, it is a hard 403 today (1/4/2022).

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Spring milestone release repo have changed URL to : https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/milestone. Quering the old DNS name is resulted in 302 redirect to a new DNS name I just provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem about version, can you try this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

refer : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

An alternative reason for this error is that pom.xml states a maven version different than the one you are actually using. I had in my pom.xml

```
       <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
```

I fixed the problem by changing the  line to:

```
<url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven3/</url>
```